# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' Writing a story?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program (using Python 3.3.2) that asks for numbers then displays a story:

http://postimg.org/image/ayd5n7suv/

But instead it outputs this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Bladibla.py", line 40, in <module>
    remaining_sweets = (int(sweets) - int(swducks)*int(ducks - 1))*int(children)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

But I don't see any mistakes on that line. Why is this so?:

```
remaining_sweets = (int(sweets) - int(swducks)*int(ducks - 1))*int(children)
```

This is all of the code:

```
#Asks for number of children
children = input("How many children are there?: ")
if int(children) > 100:
    print("That number is unimaginable! Please use a smaller number.")
    children = input("How many children are there?: ")
if int(children) < 0:
    print("That number is unimaginable! Please use a larger number.")
    children = input("How many children are there?: ")

#Asks for number of sweets
sweets = input("How many sweets do they have each?: ")
if int(sweets) > 100:
    print("If they ate that number of sweets, they would die! Please use a smaller number.")
    sweets = input("How many sweets do they have each?: ")
if int(sweets) < 0:
    print("How can they have a minus number of sweets? They can't vomit the sweets!!!! Please use a larger number.")
    sweets = input("How many sweets do they have each?: ")

#Asks for number of ducks
ducks = input("How many ducks were there?: ")
if int(ducks) > 200 :
    print("That's too many ducks! Please use a smaller number!")
    ducks = input("How many ducks were there?: ")
if int(ducks) < 0:
    print("How can there be a minus number of ducks?!! Please use a larger number")
    ducks = input("How many ducks were there?: ")

#Asks for number of sweets gave to each duck
swducks = input("How many sweets did each child give to each duck?: ")
if int(swducks) > 200 :
    print("That's too many sweets given to the ducks! Please use a smaller number!")
    swducks = input("How many sweets did each child give to each duck?: ")
if int(swducks) < 0:
    print("How can there be a minus number of sweets given to the ducks?!! Please use a larger number")
    swducks = input("How many sweets did each child give to each duck?: ")

#Outputs the 'thrilling' story
print("Please wait...")
print("There were " + children + " children each with a bag containg " + sweets + " sweets. They walked past " + ducks + " ducks. Each child gave " + swducks + " sweets to each of the ducks and ate one themselves. They decided to put the rest into a pile.")
remaining_sweets = (int(sweets) - int(swducks)*int(ducks - 1))*int(children)
print("They counted the pile and found it contained " + str(remaining_sweets) + " sweets.")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `(int(sweets) - int(swducks)*(int(ducks) - 1)))*int(children)` ?

Comment: No, Martijn Pieters answered the question. I needed to have int(ducks) - 1 NOT int(ducks - 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ducks` is a string, so `ducks - 1` fails.

You'll have to convert it to an `int` first, before subtracting 1:

```
remaining_sweets = (int(sweets) - int(swducks)*int(ducks) - 1)*int(children)
```

Comment: Such a tiny mistake in so much code! I'll have to be more careful! Thanks I'll hopefully set this as my accepted answer.